# Bootstrap Card ImgOverlay with gatsby-plugin-image not rezizing as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I have a card component id like to leverage the [Bootstrap Card ImgOverlay](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#image-overlays) for, but the image itself is coming [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/) as a `GatsbyImage`. Below is the component:

```js
const BlogPostCard = (props: BlogPostCardProps) => {
    const imageData = getImage(props.imgData)
    return (
        <Card className={style.blogPostCard}>
            <Card.ImgOverlay>
                <Card.Body className={style.blogPostCardContent}>
                    <Card.Title as="h1">{props.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Subtitle className={style.blogDate}>{props.date}</Card.Subtitle>
                    <Card.Text>{props.excerpt}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Link as={Link} to={props.slug}>Read post.</Card.Link>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card.ImgOverlay>
            <Card.Img className={style.blogPostCardImg} as={GatsbyImage} image={imageData} alt="asdf"/>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

where the `props.imgData` is coming from the following graphql fragment:

```
node {
      frontmatter {
          ...
          image {
              childImageSharp {
                  gatsbyImageData(
                      placeholder: BLURRED
                      formats: [AUTO, WEBP]
                  )
               }
          ...
       }
}
```

Here the scss is as follows:

```scss
.blogPostCardContainer {
  .blogPostCard {
    height: 300px;
    .blogPostCardContent {
      h1 {
        color: $primary-font-color;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      p {
        color: $primary-font-color;
      }

      .blogDate {
        color: $secondary-font-color;
      }
    }

    .blogPostCardImg {
      object-fit: cover;
      picture {
        opacity: 0.3;
      }
    }
  }
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is just rendering a card 300px high with the image at full width and no cropping to cover. What id really like is something equivalent to the example given in the `object-fit` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

The card should be dynamic with the `props.excerpt` length (currently just 300px), and the image should scale and crop to fill the background. Where am I going wrong in my CSS?

Comment: can you please provide any stackblitz if possible

Comment: I may be incorrect as I don't use UI packages - but GatsbyImage has attribute/props that you can use `objectFit="cover" objectPosition="center"`. I would also add that if your cards need to be dynamic, you should change your `height: 300px` too `min-height: 300px; height: 100%;` to allow for a varying height from the inner content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved by adding some `position` values to various container elements to allow one to overflow the parent and the other to govern the parent's height:

js

```js
        <Card className={style.blogPostCard}>
            <Card.Img className={style.blogPostCardImg} as={GatsbyImage} image={imageData}/>
            <Card.ImgOverlay className={style.blogPostCardContent}>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title as="h1">{props.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Subtitle>{props.date}</Card.Subtitle>
                    <Card.Text>{props.excerpt}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card.ImgOverlay>
        </Card>
```

css:

```css
.blogPostCardContainer {
  .blogPostCard {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    .blogPostCardImg {
      position: absolute;
      object-fit: cover;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .blogPostCardContent {
      position: relative;
    }

  }
}
```